# NSBundle pathForResource:ofType: doesn't find all files in application bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey. I have a Navigation-controller-based application with a number of Viewcontrollers in it which all have a property:

`NSString *infoFile;`

 in them. In the viewDidLoad:-method i assign a path to this variable using
`self.infoFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"html"]];`

To accompany my viewControllers I have a corresponding number of html-files in my resources-folder in xCode(in a group(not folder) of their own named html).

The thing is, only some of these html-files are found, trying to access other crashes my app(SIGABRT).

I'm absolutely positive that i've entered the correct file-names, i've even tried changing the file-names(and in my code accordingly) to many different ones without any positive result.

Any idea?

Comment: Where does it crash? On what line? What is the stack trace (type "bt" in your debugger console)?

Comment: Here was I thinking that having the files in the project(copied in to destination(if needed)) would grant me access to them. And so it did. After I deleted them all from the project and from the projects folder and re-adding them. So, problem solved. Thanks for your time anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: Removing all the html-files from both the project and the applications folder and re-adding them. No idea whi it didn't work from the start.

Anyway, many thanks to those of you who gave my question a portion of your time. :)